# Proper way to reframe joists to install attic ladder?

Tags: attic, joists, ladder

I'm looking to replace the attic ladder with 25.5 x 55 opening ( Century Elite AL2511R5 ). After removing my old ladder, the opening looks like the following :

[image: Exising opening]

I'm looking to change joists as follows :

[image: Future installation]

Do you think it would be strong enough ? Also, what would be the best way to attach two 2x4 together ?

[image: Photos of attic]

Comment: Since it evidently held up the ceiling and the ladder the old way, just add two 2x4 to bring the width down and call it a day. 2.5-3" construction screws, or 8-10d nails are typical for holding 2x4's together - construction adhesive can be added, too.

Comment: Unless you find your 2x4's at the "old house recycling full sized lumber" mart, your new width will be 26.5" not 25.5" since a 2x4 hasn't been anywhere near 2" x 4" for decades. You'll need some additional material sandwiched in there  if you need 25.5"

Comment: @Ecnerwal oh , indeed, thank you!!! I noticed that as well but thought something wrong with my measurements.